# Arguments of a function where another function will be called

Tags: r

Consider a hypothetical example:

```
sim <- function(n,p){
  x <- rbinom(n,1,p)
  y <- (x==0) * rnorm(n)
  z <- (x==1) * rnorm(n,5,2)

  dat <- data.frame(x, y, z)
  return(dat)
}
```

Now I want to write another function `simfun` where I will call the above `sim` function and check if `y` and `z` columns of the data frame is less than a value `k`.

```
simfun <- function(n, p, k){
   dat <- sim(n, p)
   dat$threshold <- (dat$y<=k & dat$z<=k)

  return(dat$threshold)
}
```

But is it standard to use the argument of `sim` as the argument of `simfun`? Can I write `simfun <- function(k)` and call the `sim` function inside `simfun`?

Comment: can you be more specific?, did you get any error defining `simfun`I don't see anything wrong on your code.

Comment: Why not use `replicate`?

Comment: @DavidLeal It's not giving error. But is there a way where I can have only one argument `k` in `simfun` function, but still can call `sim` function inside `simfun`.

Comment: @42- This is actually a hypothetical example. If I would give my real functions, it would irritate others.

Comment: Why you did not consider that `n,p`are defined outside the function `simfun(k)`, then you can invoke it with only one parameter. Such values can algo can be defined in `options setting. I don´t see the point, probably because from such toy example it is difficult to extrapolate to your real problem. Please try to extend a little be your hypothetical problem, it doesn't have to be your real problem.

Comment: @DavidLeal The problem is same in both my real problem and hypothetical example. While in my real problem, I have 9 arguments in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's fairly standard to do this sort of thing in R. A few pointers to consider:

Usually you should explicitly declare the argument names so as not to create any unwanted behaviour if changes are made. I.e., instead of `sim(n, p)`, write `sim(n = n, p = p)`.

To get `simfun()` down to just a `k` argument will require default values for `n` and `p`. There are lots of ways to do this. One way would be to hardcode inside `simfun` itself. E.g.:

```
simfun <- function(k) {
  dat <- sim(n = 100, p = c(.4, .6))
  dat$threshold <- (dat$y<=k & dat$z<=k)

  return(dat$threshold)
}
simfun(.5)
```

A more flexible way would be to add default values in the function declaration. When you do this, it's good practice to put variables with default values AFTER variables without default values. So `k` would come first as follow:

```
simfun <- function(k, n = 100, p = c(.4, .6)){
  dat <- sim(n, p)
  dat$threshold <- (dat$y<=k & dat$z<=k)

  return(dat$threshold)
}
simfun(.5)
```

The second option is generally preferable because you can still change `n` or `p` if you need to.

Comment: if `p=c(.4,.6)`, then in `x=rbinom(5,1,p)`, which value of `p` does `x` take?

Comment: That's just an example (as `rbinom()` accepts vectors for `p`). You can replace it with a scalar like `p = .4` For info re vectors, take a look at the help page via `?rbinom`

Comment: oh, I forgot it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While not great, you could define `n` and `p` separately

```
n <- 1
p <- .5

simfun <- function(k){
  dat <- sim(n, p)
  dat$threshold <- (dat$y<=k & dat$z<=k)
return(dat$threshold)
}
```

You can read more about R Environments here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html